# Can I use two flex-containers?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have coded a header class as a flex-container for my web page that I am designing.
I now need to carry on (as I have finished the header.)
Can I declare another flex-container in the same HTML code, but declare it as a div class, so that all the illustrations, media and other code is separate from the header?
I am relatively new to this, so sorry if that seems a daft question.

Comment: Please show relevant codes so that we can reproduced the problem you are facing

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Read this to know more about Flexbox : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ or learn how to use it with this game : http://flexboxfroggy.com/